# Самый простой способ запустить Java сервер для обращения из php

Tags: php, java

Всем привет! Имею java программу в которой ведется сложный расчет. И имею сайт на PHP который должен отправлять в java программу данные, та будет их обрабатывать и считать и отправлять назад результат. Так вот вопрос: как организовать java сервер и каким способом php и java будут общаться?

Comment: а расчет идет быстро или долго? (быстро - это несколько секунд, долго - минута и более)

Comment: Очень быстро. Просто много классов и функций которых нет в php. Расчет максимум секунда

Comment: тогда самый простой способ - это запускать жава приложение через https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.system.php да, оно не суперэффективное, но Вы его точно в несколько строк запустите, посмотрите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно для обмена между серверами и сторонними программами используют так называемое `API` реализуемое по некоторым стандартам (`SOAP`, `REST`, `RESTful`). Упрощенно говоря, на стороне сервера реализуется набор заранее заданных методов с возвращаемыми, в заранее оговоренном формате (`XML`, `JSON` и тд), данными. Вы можете как написать свой `велосипед`, так и взять готовые библиотеки, для `Java` их будет не так трудно найти.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ, я знаю про APIA, просто хотел услышать мнение людей которые реализовывали такое общение: какую библиотеку взять, какой хост недорогой купить, как защитить соединение (хотя подозреваю что обычного ключа хватит ведь по сути идет общение сервер-сервер)